# Download a file from backend with Oatpp API

Tags: http-get, oat++

There is the tutorial which describes how to upload a file to backend via POST method:

https://oatpp.io/docs/features/upload-file/

Is there Oatpp API to do the reverse operation, i.e. to download the file from backend

via GET method? Maybe there is API description or an example?

Thanks in advance.